# Cant run migration on rails app because of redis

Tags: ruby-on-rails, redis

I am trying to download a local version of Discourse, following the directions seen here:
https://meta.discourse.org/t/beginners-guide-to-install-discourse-on-macos-for-development/15772.

However, when I try to run any db command or try to start the rails server, I get the following error:

`$ bundle exec rake db:create nil versions are discouraged and will be deprecated in Rubygems 4 Discourse requires Redis 6.2.0 or up`

I know that my Redis version is 6.2.6 because I have the Redis Server running in a separate terminal. Any ideas why this error keeps happening?

Comment: Have you run bundle install?

Comment: Yes, I have. I even installed the dependencies line by line to make sure.